# Linear Regression Class in Python

Tags: python, mathematics, statistics, library, modules

I have recently been brushing up on my statistics and calculus and wanted to implement Linear Regression, the code will be for a calculus/statistics library I am working on (I know there are libraries for this but I am trying improve my both coding and math skills).

The following code works as intended. However, I feel like it has some structural flaws and I can't put my finger on what it is

```
class LinearReg:

    x = []
    y = []

    x_mean = 0
    y_mean = 0 

    b_zero = 0
    slope = 0

    def __init__(self,x,y):

        if len(x) != len(y):
            raise Error("Both axis must have the same number of values")

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.x_mean = self.axis_mean(self.x)
        self.y_mean = self.axis_mean(self.y)

    def axis_mean(self,axis):
        return sum(axis) / len(axis)


    def sum_of_deviation_products(self):
        result = 0
        for i in range(len(self.y)):
            x_dev = (self.x[i] - self.x_mean)
            y_dev = (self.y[i] - self.y_mean)
            result += x_dev * y_dev
        return result

    def sum_of_x_deviation_squared(self):
        result = 0
        for i in range(len(self.x)):
            result += (self.x[i] - self.x_mean)**2
        return result

    def get_b_zero(self):
        return self.b_zero


    def get_slope(self):
        self.slope = self.sum_of_deviation_products() / self.sum_of_x_deviation_squared()
        return self.slope

    def fit_best_line(self):
        self.b_zero = self.y_mean - (self.get_slope() * self.x_mean)
        print("The best line equation is: " + 
        "%.2f" % self.slope
         + "x + " + 
         "%.2f" % self.b_zero)
```

My primary focus is now: structure and cleanliness,

- How efficient would this play out in a large library?
- How clean and readable is the code?
- What kind of problems would I face if this class were to interact with other classes in the library?

Perhaps there is quicker way to do Linear Regression in Theory, but I'm not really interested in that right now.

Answer (score 4):

#### Toward optimized functionality and design

- since all crucial attributes `x`, `y`, `x_mean`, `y_mean` are initialized on `LinearReg` instance creation (within `__init__` method) - no need to duplicate and define them as class attributes (`x = [] ... y = []`), those should be removed as redundant
- `raise Error` - `Error` is not Python exception class. Use `Exception` or `ValueError`
- `axis_mean(self, axis)` function does not use `self` context and deserves to be just a **`@staticmethod`**
- **`sum_of_deviation_products/sum_of_x_deviation_squared`** functions 
  *Substitute algorithm:* instead of going with external variable `result` + `range(len(..))` + `for` loop - apply a convenient combination of `sum` + `enumerate` functions:

  ```
  def sum_of_deviation_products(self):
      return sum((self.x[i] - self.x_mean) * (y - self.y_mean)
              for i, y in enumerate(self.y))
  ```

  A good (or better) alternative would be `sum` + `zip` approach: `sum((x - self.x_mean) * (y - self.y_mean) for x, y in zip(self.x, self.y))`
- `get_b_zero` method is redundant as it's just return a public attribute `self.b_zero` (which is accessed directly)
- `get_slope` method 
  Instead of storing and reassigning `self.slope` attribute on each method invocation - as it's recalculated each time, it deserves to be a *computed attribute* using **`@property`** decorator:

  ```
  @property
  def slope(self):
      return self.sum_of_deviation_products() / self.sum_of_x_deviation_squared()
  ```

  Now, it's simply accessed with `self.slope`.
- **`fit_best_line`** method 
  Instead of unreadable string concatenation like `... + "%.2f" % self.slope + "x + " + "%.2f" % self.b_zero` use flexible **`f-string`** formatting:

  `print(f"The best line equation is: {self.slope:.2f}x + {self.b_zero:.2f}")`.

  The conciseness and flexibility are obvious.
  Also, in case if `b_zero` attribute/property happen to be only actual in context of `fit_best_line` call - it can be eliminated and declared as just local variable.

---

The final optimized approach:

```
class LinearReg:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        if len(x) != len(y):
            raise ValueError("Both axis must have the same number of values")

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.x_mean = self.axis_mean(self.x)
        self.y_mean = self.axis_mean(self.y)
        self.b_zero = 0

    @staticmethod
    def axis_mean(axis):
        return sum(axis) / len(axis)

    def sum_of_deviation_products(self):
        return sum((self.x[i] - self.x_mean) * (y - self.y_mean)
                   for i, y in enumerate(self.y))

    def sum_of_x_deviation_squared(self):
        return sum((x - self.x_mean) ** 2
                   for x in self.x)

    @property
    def slope(self):
        return self.sum_of_deviation_products() / self.sum_of_x_deviation_squared()

    def fit_best_line(self):
        self.b_zero = self.y_mean - (self.slope * self.x_mean)
        print(f"The best line equation is: {self.slope:.2f}x + {self.b_zero:.2f}")
```

Comment: Loop like a native, and avoid indexing.  Using `sum((x - self.x_mean) * (y - self.y_mean) for x, y in zip(self.x, self.y))` would be cleaner and faster.  Ditto for `sum((x - self.x_mean) ** 2 for x in self.x)`.

Comment: What's the use of adding `@property` in this case? Also would it be reasonable put `self.slope = self.sum_of_deviation_products() / self.sum_of_x_deviation_squared()` in the constructor? Also same goes for axis_mean.

Comment: @AJNeufeld, thanks for the hint, was writing a quick review at late night (could miss something)

Answer (score 0):

## Consistency

Your class does not seem consistent with itself.  If you create a `LinearReg` object:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [2, 3, 2.5, 4, 3.5]
lr = LinearReg(x, y)
```

The constructor computes the mean of the `x` and `y` lists, and stores these for later computations.  These means are fixed; you cannot add additional data points, as the mean will not be recomputed.

If you call `lr.get_b_zero()`, you will return the value `0`, since the `b_zero` member has not been computed.

Each time you call `lr.get_slope()`, it recomputes the slope and stores the result.  If you have changed the `x` and `y` lists, the computed value will be different ... and incorrect since the mean values have not changed.

Each time you call `fit_best_line()`, it calls `get_slope()` which recomputes the slope (possibly incorrectly if the data has changed), and uses the result to compute (or recompute) and store the `b_zero` value.  And as a side effect, it prints the line equation.

If you want to use this class to get the best fit straight line, and use the slope & intercept in other calculations, you must:

- Create the `LinearReg` object
- Call `fit_best_line()` to compute the b_zero

  - Ignore the spurious, unnecessary print output
- Call `get_slope()` (unnecessarily recomputes the slope)
- Call `get_b_zero()`.
- Use the return values.

I'm certain you'd agree this is somewhat awkward.  It would not work well in a large library.

## Stop Writing Classes

See the YouTube video [Stop Writing Classes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ZKvwuZSiyc) for more detail.

You don't need a class for this; just a single function.  This function would:

- Compute the means
- Compute the slope
- Compute the b_zero
- Return the above

A class is unnecessary, because everything can be done in this one simple function call. No state needs to be maintained.

```
from collections import namedtuple

LinearReg = namedtuple('LinearReg', 'x_mean, y_mean, slope, b_zero')

def linear_regression(x, y):

    if len(x) != len(y):
        raise ValueError("Both axis must have the same number of values")

    x_mean = sum(x) / len(x)
    y_mean = sum(y) / len(y)

    sum_x2_dev = sum((xi - x_mean) ** 2 for xi in x)
    sum_xy_dev = sum((xi - x_mean) * (yi - y_mean) for xi, yi in zip(x, y))

    slope = sum_xy_dev / sum_x2_dev
    b_zero = y_mean - slope * x_mean

    return LinearReg(x_mean, y_mean, slope, b_zero)
```

Usage:

```
>>> lr = linear_regression([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 2.5, 4, 3.5])
>>> lr.slope
0.4
>>> lr.b_zero
1.7999999999999998
```

We can slightly beefed up the `namedtuple`, adding some convenience methods to it:

```
class LinearReg(namedtuple('LinearReg', 'x_mean, y_mean, slope, b_zero')):

    def __str__(self):
        return f"The best line equation is: {self.slope:.2f}x + {self.b_zero:.2f}"

    def __call__(self, x):
        """
        Interpolation/extrapolation: return y-value for a given x-value
        """
        return self.slope * x + self.b_zero
```

And then we'd additionally have:

```
>>> str(lr)
'The best line equation is: 0.40x + 1.80'
>>> lr(6)
4.2
```

## A Use Case for a Class

If your `LinearReg` object allowed additional data points to be added, then you would have "state" which could be maintained in your object.  And then it would make sense to recompute the slope and b_zero values when requested.

Comment: I get your point on not writing a class for this purpose, however I feel like when creating a function for this purpose, it hurts the readablity (not saying my class is super readable but I feel like it's more clear to see what's going on).

Answer (score 0):

Some good points have been said, I'm not going over those again. Just wanted to say that your code is probably meant to be used by someone else. Even if it's not, your API should reflect what your code will be working on.
I would not take 2 arrays for input, but an array of 2d coordinates. Then, if for your computation it's easier to split those coordinates in 2 arrays, do this inside your code.

My 2 cents.